# Store ndarray in a PyTable (and how to define the Col()-type)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pytables

*TL;DR*: I have a PyTable with a float32 Col and get an error when writing a numpy-float32-array into it. **(How) can I store a numpy-array (float32) in the Column of a PyTables table?**

---

I'm new to PyTables - following a recommendation of [TFtables](http://%20http://tftables.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html) (a lib to use HDF5 in Tensorflow), I'm using it to store all my HDF5 data (currently distributed in batches in several files with each three datasets) within a table in a single HDF5 file. Datasets are

```
'data' : (n_elements, 1024, 1024, 4)@float32
'label' : (n_elements, 1024, 1024, 1)@uint8
'weights' : (n_elements, 1024, 1024, 1)@float32
```

where the `n_elements` are distributed over several files that I want to merge into one now (to allow unordered access).

So when I build my table, I figured each dataset represents a column. I built everything in a generic way that allows to do this for an arbitrary number of datasets:

```
# gets dtypes (and shapes) of the dsets (accessed by dset_keys = ['data', 'label', 'weights']
dtypes, shapes = _determine_shape(hdf5_files, dset_keys)

# to dynamically generate a table, I'm using a dict (not a class as in the PyTables tutorials)
# the dict is (conform with the doc): { 'col_name' : Col()-class-descendent }
table_description = {dset_keys[i]: tables.Col.from_dtype(dtypes[i]) for i in range(len(dset_keys))}

# create a file, a group-node and attach a table to it
h5file = tables.open_file(destination_file, mode="w", title="merged")
group = h5file.create_group("/", 'main', 'Node for data table')
table = h5file.create_table(group, 'data_table', table_description, "Collected data with %s" % (str(val_keys)))
```

The dtypes that I get for each dsets (read with h5py) are obviously the ones of the numpy arrays (ndarray) that reading the dset returns: `float32` or `uint8`. So the Col()-types are `Float32Col` an `UInt8Col`. I naively assumed that I can now write a float32-array into this col, but filling in data with:

```
dummy_data = np.zeros([1024,1024,3], float32) # normally data read from other files

sample = table.row
sample['data'] = dummy_data
```

results in ``` TypeError: invalid type (<class 'numpy.ndarray'>) for column ``data`` ```. So now I feel stupid for assuming I'd be able to write an array in there, BUT there are no "ArrayCol()" types offered, neither are there any hints in the [PyTables doc](https://www.pytables.org/usersguide/libref/declarative_classes.html#colclassdescr) as to whether or how it is possible to write an array into a column. How do I do this?

There are "shape" arguments in the Col() class and it's descendents, so it should be possible, otherwise what are these for?!

Comment: wouldn't mind some constructive criticism as to why this question was downvoted... I've put quite some work into it.

Comment: Yeah, I also don't understand why the question was downvoted, so I voted it up – as I have the same question and it's well described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Edit:*** I just saw that the `tables.Col.from_type(type, shape)` allows using the precision of a type (float32 instead of float alone). The rest stays the same (takes a string and shape).

---

The factory function `tables.Col.from_kind(kind, shape)` can be used to construct a Col-Type that supports ndarrays. What "kind" is and how to use this isn't documented anywhere I found; however with trial and error I found that allowed "kind"s are **strings** of basic datatypes. I.e.: `'float'`, `'uint'`, ... **without the precision** (NOT `'float64'`)

Since I get numpy.dtypes from h5py reading a dataset (`dset.dtype`), these have to be cast to str and the precision needs to be removed.
In the end the relevant lines look like this:

```
# get key, dtype and shapes of elements per dataset from the datasource files
val_keys, dtypes, element_shapes = _get_dtypes(datasources, element_axis=element_axis)

# for storing arrays in columns apparently one has to use "kind"
# "kind" cannot be created with dtype but only a string representing 
# the dtype w/o precision, e.g. 'float' or 'uint' 
dtypes_kind = [''.join(i for i in str(dtype) if not i.isdigit()) for dtype in dtypes]

# create table description as dictionary
description = {val_keys[i]: tables.Col.from_kind(dtypes_kind[i], shape=element_shapes[i]) for i in range(len(val_keys))}
```

Then writing data into the table finally works as suggested:

```
sample = table.row
sample[key] = my_array
```

Since it all felt a bit "hacky" and isn't documented well, I am still wondering, whether this is not an intended use for PyTables and would leave this question open for abit to see if s.o. knows more about this...

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late, but I think the answer to your problem lies in the shape parameter for Float32Col.

Here's how it's used in the documentation:

`from tables import *
from numpy import *

# Describe a particle record
class Particle(IsDescription):
    name        = StringCol(itemsize=16)  # 16-character string
    lati        = Int32Col()              # integer
    longi       = Int32Col()              # integer
    pressure    = Float32Col(shape=(2,3)) # array of floats (single-precision)
    temperature = Float64Col(shape=(2,3)) # array of doubles (double-precision)

# Open a file in "w"rite mode
fileh = open_file("tutorial2.h5", mode = "w")

# Get the HDF5 root group
root = fileh.root

# Create the groups:
for groupname in ("Particles", "Events"):
    group = fileh.create_group(root, groupname)

# Now, create and fill the tables in Particles group
gparticles = root.Particles

# Create 3 new tables
for tablename in ("TParticle1", "TParticle2", "TParticle3"):
    # Create a table
    table = fileh.create_table("/Particles", tablename, Particle, "Particles: "+tablename)

    # Get the record object associated with the table:
    particle = table.row

    # Fill the table with 257 particles
    for i in xrange(257):
        # First, assign the values to the Particle record
        particle['name'] = 'Particle: %6d' % (i)
        particle['lati'] = i
        particle['longi'] = 10 - i

        ########### Detectable errors start here. Play with them!
        particle['pressure'] = array(i*arange(2*3)).reshape((2,4))  # Incorrect
        #particle['pressure'] = array(i*arange(2*3)).reshape((2,3)) # Correct
        ########### End of errors

        particle['temperature'] = (i**2)     # Broadcasting

        # This injects the Record values
        particle.append()

    # Flush the table buffers
    table.flush()`

Here's the link to the part of the documentation I'm referring to
[https://www.pytables.org/usersguide/tutorials.html](https://www.pytables.org/usersguide/tutorials.html#multidimensional-table-cells-and-automatic-sanity-checks)

Comment: thank you for your contribution :) for me it definetly is too late and I don't know when I'll be working with PyTables the next time. I might check and validate what you're suggesting. If somebody reads this and finds this answer to be better than what I've come up with, please comment - I will mark this to be the right answer then.